# Resize datafile oracle using execute immediate

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, execute-immediate, data-files

I need resize this datafile      '+GMPDATDESA01/prod/datafile/apps_ts_tx_idx.269.878649919', why this simple  procedure is wrong?.

Other options, plis?

```
SQL> begin
      2  execute immediate 'alter database datafile '+GMPDATDESA01/prod/datafile/apps_ts_tx_idx.269.878649919' resize 732M';
      3  exit;
      4  /
    execute immediate 'alter database datafile '+GMPDATDESA01/prod/datafile/apps_ts_tx_idx.269.878649919' resize 732M';


                                                                                *
```

> ERROR at line 2:
>       ORA-06550: line 2, column 87:
>       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ".269" when expecting one of the following:
>       . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
>       return returning  <> or != or ~= >= <= <>
>       and or like like2 like4 likec between into using || bulk
>       member submultiset

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to anticipate and escape ' in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27373158/how-to-anticipate-and-escape-in-oracle)

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape single quote (') with double quote ('')

```
begin
      execute immediate 'alter database datafile ''+GMPDATDESA01/prod/datafile/apps_ts_tx_idx.269.878649919'' resize 732M';
end;
/
```

But why are you using dynamic sql? You can just write

```
alter database datafile '+GMPDATDESA01/prod/datafile/apps_ts_tx_idx.269.878649919' resize 732M';
```

in sqlplus?

Comment: You don't escape a single quote (also known as an apostrophe) with double-quotes (quotation marks) - you use two apostrophes, one after the other. The code is correct, but the explanation is confusing.

Comment: Yes, in sqlplus, I'm doing a procedure to maintenance of tablespaces, will be automatic.

Comment: But, this statement is a problem.

Comment: SQL> begin
  2  execute immediate 'alter database datafile ''+GMPDATDESA01/prod/datafile/apps_ts_tx_idx.269.878649919'' resize 8500M';
  3  exit;
  4  /
exit;
    *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-06550: line 3, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the
following:
( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
null pragma raise return select update while with
<an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
<a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock
insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
merge pipe purg

Comment: @SandyRamirez - your line 3 is `exit;` instead of `end;` which isn't right for a PL/SQL block?

Comment: Thanks for your answers!!! .....This statement too running : execute immediate 'alter database datafile ||''''||+GMPDATDESA01/prod/datafile/apps_ts_tx_idx.269.878649919'||''''|| ' resize 732M';