# Escape & symbol with space in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am struck with following query. Please help me on this.

```
select 
      case when column in ('1 Chelsea'|| chr(38) ||
      'Friend (2)','5 Manchester''s Song'||chr(38)||
      'Hamilton') then 'Others' else N/A
from FA
```

Output of above query

```
1 Chelsea & Friend (2)          N/A
5 Manchester's Song&Hamilton   Others
```

From the above query the output should be like the following output

```
1 Chelsea & Friend (2)          Others
5 Manchester's Song&Hamilton   Others
```

Please someone help me on this. Also note that the I dont have access to use `SET DEFINE OFF`.

Comment: *I dont have access to use SET DEFINE OFF* What do you mean you don't have access? If you can execute the SQL, then why not `SET DEFINE OFF`?

Answer (score 1):

A ' in an SQL string has to be escaped with another '. So `'my ''house'''` means `my 'house'` actually.

Hence `'5 Manchester''s Song'` doesnt match `5 Manchester''s Song`, but `5 Manchester's Song`. You must query for `'5 Manchester''''s Song'` instead.

BTW: It is not necessary to use chr(38), you could use & directly:

```
select 
  case when column in (
    '1 Chelsea & Friend (2)',
    '5 Manchester''''s Song&Hamilton'
  ) then 'Others' else 'N/A' end
from FA;
```

Comment: I prefer  Quoting string literal technique.

Comment: *BTW: It is not necessary to use chr(38), you could use & directly:* No, it will prompt for substitution.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B: Okay, then this is something special in SQL Developer. A strange (and probably annoying) feature. Does that tool have no setting to switch it off?

Comment: Most of the GUI based client tools are capable of executing the SQL*Plus commands. `SET DEFINE OFF` would work fine.

Comment: I have updated correct output of query now. Apologies

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two things:

- **SET DEFINE OFF** or, `CHR(38)` to get rid off the **substitution operator** `&`

Most of the **GUI based client tools** are capable of executing the **SQL*Plus commands**. Execute it once in the **session** or **SQL Worksheet** in **SQL Developer**, and it won't prompt you again to enter a **substitution value**:

```
SET DEFINE OFF
```

- Better use the [**Quoting string literal technique**](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/12/31/quoting-string-literal-technique-to-avoid-erros-due-to-single-quotation-marks-in-the-string/)

> '5 Manchester''''s Song'

Using quoting string literal technique, it could just be written as:

```
q'[Manchester's Song&Hamilton]'
```

For example,

```
SQL> SET DEFINE OFF
SQL> WITH DATA(a, b) AS(
  2  SELECT 1,  'Chelsea & Friend (2)' FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 5, q'[Manchester's Song&Hamilton]' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 6, 'abcd' FROM DUAL
  5  )
  6  SELECT a,
  7    CASE
  8      WHEN b IN ('Chelsea & Friend (2)',q'[Manchester's Song&Hamilton]')
  9      THEN 'Others'
 10      ELSE 'N/A'
 11    END status
 12  FROM DATA
 13  /

         A STATUS
---------- ------
         1 Others
         5 Others
         6 N/A

SQL>
```

Regarding a more detailed example on the quoting string literal technique see this answer [How to anticipate and escape single quote ' in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27373158/how-to-anticipate-and-escape-in-oracle/27373394#27373394)

Comment: I have updated correct output of query now. Apologies