# Formatting execute immediate with to_date ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql, to-date, execute-immediate

Am stuck on a formatting procedure within a package..... script works ok however integrating it with a package is proving difficult!!

Am not used to oracle...I have script running but not in package...well not all of it...Drop Table worked

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Testing is
    PROCEDURE DropTable1 IS         
        BEGIN
                execute immediate ('DROP TABLE mytable1');                           
        END;

    PROCEDURE PopulateTable1 IS
        BEGIN
            execute immediate ('CREATE TABLE mytable1
            AS (   
                select
                substr(t1.genarea,3,3) as M_Class,
                substr(t1.genarea,6,30) as M_Description,
                substr(t1.genarea,36,3) as M_Class,
                substr(t1.genarea,39,30) as M_Description,
                substr(t1.itemitem,1,3) as product_code,
                t3.CHANNEL_NUM as SALES_CHANNEL,
                to_date(''t2.time_id'',''dd-mon-yyyy'') as mis_date,
                sum(t2.ap_cw_cfi_irp+t2.ap_cw_issues_irp) as ap_gross,
                sum(t2.Ap_Cw_Cfi_Irp+t2.Ap_Revivals_Irp) as ap_net,
                sum(t2.sp_inc_irp+t2.sp_issues_irp) as sp_gross,
                sum(t2.sp_dec_irp+t2.sp_fs_irp) as sp_net
              from
                d_pr t1, act t2, age_map t3
              where
                t1.pfx=''IT'' and t1.coy=''1'' and t1.tabl=''T81'' and substr(t1.itemitem,1,3) = t2.product_id and t3.AGE_NUM = t2.age_id
              group by
                substr(t1.genarea,3,3),
                substr(t1.genarea,6,30),
                substr(t1.genarea,36,3),
                substr(t1.genarea,39,30),
                substr(t1.itemitem,1,3),
                t3.CHANNEL_NUM,
                to_date(''t2.time_id'',''dd-mon-yyyy'')
            )');
            COMMIT;
        END PopulateTable1;
END Testing;
/
```

thanks

Comment: When you have a problem like this, assign the string to a variable and the print it to the screen using DBMS_Output. That will show you the exact SQL that is being submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have quotes around `t2.time_id`. Single quotes are used to indicate a string literal; that's clearly a column reference.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things in your code which seems odd:

- `to_date(''t2.time_id'',''dd-mon-yyyy'')`

You don't need any **single quotation-marks** around the column, you only need single-quotation marks around a **string literal**. Change it to:

```
to_date(t2.time_id,''dd-mon-yyyy'')
```

If you are struggling with single quotation marks at multiple places, then I would suggest **[Quoting string literal technique](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/12/31/quoting-string-literal-technique-to-avoid-erros-due-to-single-quotation-marks-in-the-string/)** to avoid errors due to single-quotation marks in the string. For example, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27373394/3989608

- `COMMIT;`

You don't need **COMMIT** for **DDL** statements, you need commit only for **DML** statements. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
execute immediate ('CREATE TABLE mytable1 AS 
(select to_date(/*remove single quotes here*/t2.time_id/*and here*/,''dd-mon-yyyy'') as mis_date 
from (select current_date time_id from dual) t2)');
end;
```

And in the last line of the select query. Because it is getting treated as string