# How to handle a single quote in Oracle SQL with long text

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I insert a record in a column having CLOB data type(so big text) having single quote in it?

I've already seen

[How to handle a single quote in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875257/how-to-handle-a-single-quote-in-oracle-sql)

but the solution is make it manual and I'm trying to insert Long text which contains lot of single quotes. Once Oracle detects ',  my INSERT doesn't work.

My question is if there is a kind of command like "set define off" where I can tell Oracle to disable the ' in the text

Comment: See [**How to anticipate and escape ' in oracle**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27373394/3989608)

Comment: Please don't use the "SQL Server" tag for Oracle questions. Use "SQL" instead (I've re-tagged it for you).

Comment: @FrankSchmitt thanks  !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the [Q'](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm) operator; for example:

```
create table t_clob ( a clob)

insert into t_clob values (q'[START aa'a''aa aa 'a'' aa'a'  a'a' a END]')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use quoted notation:

`SELECT q'|text'containing'quotes|' FROM DUAL`

The pipes can be replaced by any matching symbol. It must be the same symbol at the beginning and at the end except when parentheses are used, then `()`, `[]` or `{}`.

See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218

Comment: hi @Husqvik  i dont want to sound so stupied but how can i that implemet it like an insert ,i mean , i m reading somethings about   "sele from dual" but what i want is in the form inser into tablename values (Value1,Value2..) what have that in relationship with a select ?

Comment: @Enrique The answer is explaining the syntax you should use, you have to adapt it to your needs. Just edited my answer to show an `insert` example

Answer (score 2):

You can use `''` to skip the meaning of the `Quotation`

```
select 'hello this''s an example for '' in between string ' from dual
```